# What is the usual website screenshot size and ratio?

Tags: website-design, image, size

I would like to show a list of website screenshots taken by an user.

An user has to take a screenshot of its own website and send it though a form.
Then I'll show all minimized screenshots in a list view.

What is the usual website screenshot size that I can ask?
What dimension should I ask?

Comment: if you want to capture the size of what they actually see, don't specify dimensions.. if you are not interested in that info, but really need to standardize, ask for whatever you aim for. note that very few might actually comply with your requirement unless you are their boss..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, at least in most used programming languages you have a way to resize the image before or after uploading, so **in that case you wouldn't have the need to restrict the image upload** to any resolution.

If this is not in your plans, you have to decide **what will be the purpose of the screenshots** on your app and then **ask for max resolution you'd for that purpose**.

**"The usual size" is not a static thing**. Resolutions change with time.

The correct resolution for the image will be will be the one who fits:

1. **Expected use**: You could want to display screenshots in one of this ways:

   - Users are able to appreciate details (large image)
   - Users can get a decent idea of the structure and  content of the page, but doesn't have to much details. (mid-sized image).
   - Users just need to recognize the page and then, if they want more detail, they can click on the small image to expand it. (small and then mid/large)
2. **Users resolution**: If you already have data about your visitors (from Google Analytics [for example](https://01456665495003716876.googlegroups.com/attach/9bf2004640845481/untitled.JPG?part=0.1&view=1&vt=ANaJVrE2ud_zd1RPazIyj01h9_kKq2LMhVRGlwh4Nh5BVrVJi2UfIir_88AjKuhMSN8pk36R42jpEzKHHFWEwyl-tBjKxDZY_6_iNYWTnQmYwVbt1emU9ko)) you could take a look at them to see what's the most used. If you don't have enough data, you can take some reference from the [W3 Screen Resolutions Statistics](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_display.asp) taking in count that for 2015 the % will go towards higher resolutions.   Once you have that information, you have to take in count the "Expected use" point.

[image]

3. **Device**: On a mobile platform it will be pointless to show a small image because the user won't be able to clearly appreciate anything on it (maybe just the color scheme).

Answer (score 1):

This is dependent on the type of site you (or your users) have built.

If it is mobile, sticking with and iPhone resolution or 640 by 1136 pixels is great for showing a mobile screen shot.

For desktop? You should use a grid sized screen shot, which can vary from 960 pixels wide to 1170. The height is up to you.

Screen size is not as important as the content you want to show, as well as keeping uniformity across how you display them.

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome's "new tab" page uses relatively small (~140x80) thumbnails.

This, coupled with the page's title is clearly enough to quickly identify most sites. Especially so considering these are the pages you visit most often.

However, consider this point:
In your case, the users will be looking at screenshots from their own websites. Meaning, one website. 
So, unlike in Chrome, they will all be quite similar. Same cholor scheme, same header (usually). Imagine all New Tab suggestions would be different pages from the same website. It will be much harder to differentiate one from the other.

So, I think a set of screenshots from **one** website would require larger thumbnails.